# How do I create AspNetUser tables in ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm going through an ASP.NET MVC5 course where the instructor is building the database through code-first migration.

For reasons too complicated to go into here, I'm trying to build it through database-first. So instead of creating the code and then updating the database, I'm simply building the tables in SQL Server and then updating the model from the database. All is going fine except I have two questions:

1. Apparently we're supposed to have an `AspNetUser` table in the database that I don't see because we selected "Individual User Authentication" when creating the project, I guess because I did not enable migrations. How can I get this created? The code I downloaded has an `IdentityModels.cs` but I'm afraid to use both code-first and data-first, as it might mess up the database I already have in there.
2. In another lesson, the instructor added, in the entity class, to the getter statement. I can't add this to the EF-created model because it will overwrite if I update the model from the database. Is there any other way I can enter this logic? Maybe in the controller?

Please don't ask me why I'm "defying" the course and doing it data first, it's complicated.

Comment: Are you using EF Core, or Entity Framework 6? With the latter, it's possible to do a hybrid, where you create the "code first" models from an existing database. If you're relying on an .edmx file, that's more complicated.

Comment: Also: https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/ - a bit old, but seems to match what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using EF6. So what you're saying is that I can still turn on migrations and run the Entity code even with an existing database and it won't overwrite?

Comment: No. You can let Entity Framework create the models from an existing database. It would be up to you, then, whether to enable migrations, or to do your updates manually.

Comment: There's always the option to generate update scripts, if you want to run them manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#getting-a-sql-script

Comment: Thanks but the link you gave me above assumes code first migrations. The issue is that I cannot enable migrations at all, I get an error message something like  
 
System.NotSupportedException: Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created using Database First or Model First is not supported.

So now I'm completely lost I have NOOO idea what it's saying above. This shouldn't be that complex, right? Should get an ASPNETUser table without re-creating db from scratch code-first

Comment: Yeah, that last link does require Code First. You can do Code First from an existing database, though. How _are_ you creating your mapping? If you're using the version that generates an .edmx file, you're not going to be able to follow any instructions that expect you to be able to change the models which the .tt files generate (as you saw already).

Answer (score 0):

Found a script for those tables and ran them in SQL Server. Done. No migrations or entities or any of that stuff. Because enable-migrations has NEVER worked for me, and code-first to me is so counterintuitive.